# Where to complain about applicaton in Software Center?

Tags: software-center, malware, canonical

Recently I tried applicaton Qstamina-snap.
And when I opened it there another window appear with advertising and I can't use application itself, when I close ad then app close too. And I'm not sure if such stuff doesn't violate some rules. I hope those app wasn't malware.

*UPDATE: there still only one vote on this question. Really ? Nobody cares where they could complain in such case ?*

[image]

Here is where I install apps from (usual Software Center):
[image]

Comment: Was this installed from a snap or the generic "Software Center"?  Can you specifically show the window you used to 'install' the software from?

Comment: So, firstly, this is not Malware.  The actual [snap application page](https://snapcraft.io/qstamina-snap) says you need to donate to use the app.  This might violate parts of the Snapcraft Store rules and regulations however I am not a lawyer.  As Canonical operates the snapcraft store your contacts would probably be the support team at Canonical; however I cannot verify this officially.

Comment: @Thomas Ward see window above - it is generic Software Center. Thanks for info. About contacting Canonical - I didn't find contacts for non-corporate users.

Comment: You could ask here as far as snaps requiring payment (though I don't see why not allowed, all the other app stores have pay to use apps.. https://community.ubuntu.com/c/desktop

Comment: @doug such apps need to be on the app store *needing money to purchase them*, if I'm reading the Terms of the Snapcraft store.  Which the Ubuntu Software Center *also* shows options for

Comment: It does appear that they may be skirting Canonical's fee for distributing the snap. There isn't any easily found method to report directly, I mentioned one place to start a topic, another would be https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/store

Comment: The bad stuff is that I don't see that it's paid.  I expect payment to be asked before download or at lest it should be mentioned.

Comment: This def seems mega scummy. There seems to be a hole in the ability to report this kind of stuff in general. Even with Software Center etc.